# Where does k2 component store its images in the database?

Tags: joomla, components, joomla-k2

I want to retrieve/query images stored by joomla k2 component (under the Image Tab).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To display the K2 item image you can use this

```
echo "media/k2/items/cache/".md5("Image".K2 ITEM ID HERE)."_XL.jpg";
```

Comment: Not everybody is a programmer or know about databases and phpMyAdmin. You should / could explain where this line could be put.

Comment: For anyone not using PHP it's basically `md5("Image1212")` where 1212 is the ID of the K2 item. Remember capital `I` in Image.

Answer (score 23):

**It's not stored in the database at all.**

They use the md5 hash on the actual K2 item ID, and that is how they rename and save the image in the folder `media/k2/items/cache/`.

Anywhere the K2 item is pulled up, they use `JFile::exists` (which is used to check if a file exists in the path set) with the path

```
URL-ROOT."media/k2/items/cache/".md5("image" . K2 ITEM ID HERE)."_XL.jpg"
```

and if the file is there, it shows the image.

Also, the `_XL.jpg` will change depending on what size the image is set to display on the page, be it a thumbnail, large, XL, etc.

I know that isn't what you wanted to hear, but that is how they do it :) Hope that helps man!

Comment: Thank you Caleb, actually i was looking at this file modules/mod_k2_content/helper.php and show how images were displayed and surely you have clarified it for me. Cheers

Comment: This solution was slightly wrong.  The md5 function needs to have "Image" before the K2 Item ID like it is in surya's answer. 

So it should be:
 URL-ROOT."media/k2/items/cache/".md5('Image'.K2 ITEM ID HERE)."_XL.jpg"

Answer (score 3):

Though you got the answer sharing the info may be helpful:

If working within the K2 Templates (Html overrides) following can be used to access the image added via K2 image tab.

```
$this->item->image
```

OR

```
$this->item->imageXLarge (size you want)
```

you get relative url : **/media/k2/items/cache/29642a1d30cebf98734fb424b2b1316b_L.jpg**

Answer (score 1):

You can find the originals in the media/k2/items/src/ directory. Also, @David is correct, "Image" is needed as prefix to the k2 item id.